# valid values of p for a probabilty function

Tags: probability

Let $P$ be a probability function on $\Omega=\{ a,b\}$ such that  for p  $0 \leq p\leq 1$.

$$\begin{aligned}
P(a)&=p
\\P(b)&=1-p
\end{aligned}$$ 
 Let $Q$ be a function on $\Omega$ be defined by $Q(\omega) = [P(w)]^2$ For what values of $p$ will $Q$ be a valid probability function?

---

Definition Probability Function

Given a random expirement with discrete sample space $\Omega$, a probability function $P$ is a function $\Omega$ with the following properties

1. $P(\omega) \geq 0, \forall \omega \in \Omega$
2. $\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} P(w)=1$
3. For all events $A \subseteq \Omega$
   $$ P(A)= \sum_{\omega \in A} P(w)$$

___________________-

for 1 any value of p wokrs

for 2 $p(a)+p(b)=p+(1-p)=1$

for 3 all of the p on the value still

I think that it is for the p within $[0,1]$

***Need to square it still*** I just checked for $P$ being a probability function not $Q$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a solution of $p^2+(1-p)^2=1$ so $p\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Yes, it is just the solution to the equation that you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

We have $Q(\{a\})=p^2$ and $Q(\{b\})=(1-p)^2$. Now, $Q$ must satisfy $Q(\{a,b\})=1$, which is true if and only if $$p^2 + (1-p)^2 = 1. $$
This is equivalent to
$$
2p(1-p) = 0,
$$
which is true if and only if $p=0$ or $p=1$.